# How do I select count(distinct someColumn) from someKeySpace.someTable... in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, count, distinct, cql, udf

I need to get a unique clientid count from my cassandra database.  I know I can't accomplish this with the following piece of CQL code:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT clientid)
FROM somekeyspace.sometable
WHERE transdate > '2017-05-06'
      AND transdate < '2017-05-07'
      AND locationid = 1;
```

This question has been posted by others on stackoverflow, yet i can't seem to get a good answer.  Can I solve this with a UDF, and if so what would that look like?

The issue i have with a UDF is that i don't know how to pass in an entire column of values as a parameter.

Comment: What is your table schema ?

Comment: primary key(clientid, locationID, transactionDetail)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely "Use spark" and a good cache.

Could invert the table, do something like create a table, keyed on transdate that stores a clientids `(transdate, clientid)` then iterate through all of the yyyy-mm-dd's in your range, and `count(*)` add them together. If you have more then 5000 or so clientids per day that probably wont scale (count aggregation is very expensive). could add more partition buckets to transdate like `yyyy-mm-ddThh:00:00` to do it by hour or 15 min (round up to nearest 15 min).

Can do like above but have a job that precomputes and saves the daily totals for historical ones, so that way only "today" count is expensive. Can offload the "today" count onto redis (hyper log log if ok with some % error would be great fit) or something if you need it super fast too and can flush at end of day.